# Remove specific cookie on firefox

Tags: user-interface, debugging, firefox, cookies

I am doing some testing of firefox and got myself into situation where I need some cookies to be present while some others to be removed. I could write javascript that would do this, but was wondering if there is a way to do it via UI, like it can be done on Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a raw firefox:

First click on the small earth/lock logo at the left of the address:

[image: Click on favicon]

Then click on "More informations"

In the popup, click "See the cookies"

In the second pop-up, you can selected and delete any cookie.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I remove specific cookies on firefox

You can do this with the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) extension, which adds various web developer tools to the browser.

1. Right click on page
2. Select `Web Developer`
3. Select `Cookies
4. Select `View Cookie Information`

   [image]
5. The resulting tab/window has options to `Delete` and `Edit` the cookies for the current web page.

   [image]